# its signing in on the emulator, but not working on my cellphone

Tags: android

how is everybody its signing in in the emulator, but not working on my cellphone, my emulator is version 8 and my cellphone is version 6.0.1.
how is everybody its signing in in the emulator, but not working on my cellphone, my emulator is version 8 and my cellphone is version 6.0.1.how is everybody its signing in in the emulator, but not working on my cellphone, my emulator is version 8 and my cellphone is version 6.0.1.

---

```
package com.example.oliver.eatit;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.oliver.eatit.Interface.ItemClickListener;
import com.example.oliver.eatit.Model.Category;
import com.example.oliver.eatit.ViewHolder.MenuViewHolder;
import com.example.oliver.eatit.common.Common;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class Home extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

FirebaseDatabase database;
DatabaseReference category;
TextView txtFullName;
RecyclerView recycler_menu;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category,MenuViewHolder> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("Menu");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //Init Firebase
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    category = database.getReference("Category");

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent cartIntent =  new Intent(Home.this, Cart.class);
        startActivity(cartIntent);
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    //set Name for user
    View headerView= navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    txtFullName = (TextView)headerView.findViewById(R.id.txtFullName);
    txtFullName.setText(Common.currentUser.getName());

    //Load menu
    recycler_menu=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_menu);
    recycler_menu.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager =  new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recycler_menu.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    loadMenu();

}

private void loadMenu() {

    adapter= new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category, MenuViewHolder>(Category.class,R.layout.menu_item,MenuViewHolder.class,category) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(MenuViewHolder viewHolder, Category model, int position) {
            viewHolder.txtMenuName.setText(model.getName());
            Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(model.getImage()).into(viewHolder.imageView);
            final Category clickItem=model;
            viewHolder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean islongClick) {
                  //Get categoryID and send to new activity
                    Intent foodlist = new Intent(Home.this,Foodlist.class);
                    foodlist.putExtra("CategoryId",adapter.getRef(position).getKey());
                    startActivity(foodlist);
                }
            });
        }
    };
    recycler_menu.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
    return true;
}


@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_menu) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_cart) {

        Intent cartintent =  new Intent(Home.this, Cart.class);
        startActivity(cartintent);

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_orders) {
        Intent orderintent =  new Intent(Home.this, OrderStatus.class);
        startActivity(orderintent);

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_log_out) {
        Intent signin =  new Intent(Home.this, SignIn.class);
        signin.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(signin);

    }
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:background="@drawable/background"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_home"
    android:background="@color/overlayBackground"
    app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
    app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"

    app:menu="@menu/activity_home_drawer" />
```

---

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.oliver.eatit"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1

    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

//library
//noinspection GradleCompatible
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.2'
compile 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5'
compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
//noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26+'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26+'
compile 'com.cepheuen.elegant-number-button:lib:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.2'
//noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
compile 'com.android.support:design:26+'
compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
//compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.5'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.2'
//noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26+'
//noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
compile 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26+'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

---

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.oliver.eatit, PID: 31191
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.oliver.eatit/com.example.oliver.eatit.Home}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3253)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                  at com.example.oliver.eatit.Home.onCreate(Home.java:43)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:657)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:1001)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:843)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                  at com.example.oliver.eatit.Home.onCreate(Home.java:43) 
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876) 
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
               Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:631)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:1001) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:843) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                  at com.example.oliver.eatit.Home.onCreate(Home.java:43) 
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876) 
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.drawable.Drawable android.graphics.drawable.Drawable$ConstantState.newDrawable()' on a null object reference
                  at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable$ChildDrawable.<init>(LayerDrawable.java:1723)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable$LayerState.<init>(LayerDrawable.java:1792)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable$RippleState.<init>(RippleDrawable.java:999)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.createConstantState(RippleDrawable.java:990)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.createConstantState(RippleDrawable.java:96)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.mutate(LayerDrawable.java:1652)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.mutate(RippleDrawable.java:976)
                  at android.view.View.applyBackgroundTint(View.java:18731)
                  at android.view.View.setBackgroundDrawable(View.java:18607)
                  at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.access$001(FloatingActionButton.java:68)
                  at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton$ShadowDelegateImpl.setBackgroundDrawable(FloatingActionButton.java:824)
                at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButtonLollipop.setBackgroundDrawable(Fl
```

Comment: the problem seems to be here  com.example.oliver.eatit.Home.onCreate(Home.java:43)   however the question about a certificate for your app here https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html

Comment: Home.java:43, its the on create method in the main activity after pressing sign in

Comment: Please post your XML Layout for the "Home" activity. And your `onCreate` method